# How to ensure that adjusting a TrackBar control with a mouse will set values multiple of SmallChange and not any in between?

Tags: winforms, trackbar

I used .Net trackbar control. My trackbar point is 0...5...10..15.
 Problem is, when user scrolled trackbar they easily drop scroll in between points. But i wan't to that user only drop the scroll in my display point only. like they set only 0,5,10 etc. Not they set 6,7,8,9...

I set SmallChanges property with 5 value. But they working with keyboard changes not with mouse scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply force the Value property to be a multiple of the SmallChange property by overriding its value in an event handler for the ValueChanged event.  Like this:

```
    private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var bar = (TrackBar)sender;
        if (bar.Value % bar.SmallChange != 0) {
            bar.Value = bar.SmallChange * ((bar.Value + bar.SmallChange / 2) / bar.SmallChange);
        }
    }
```

Note that this even works while the user is dragging the thumb with the mouse, like it behaves when he uses the keyboard.  I assumed that's what you wanted.

Comment: Interesting solution. There are some corner cases (like LargeChange not being a multiple of SmallChange will cause rounding problems). The simpler solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202679/force-trackbar-value-to-be-a-ten-multiple?lq=1 is also interesting and causes less user-code to be called.