# Force trackbar value to be a ten multiple

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I added a trackbar on a Winform project with C#.

```
mySlider.Minimum = 0;
mySlider.Maximum = 200;
mySlider.Value = 30;
mySlider.SmallChange = 10;
mySlider.LargeChange = 10;
mySlider.TickFrequency = 10;
```

I would like to be able to select only ten multiples value.
I don't found a solution in order to do this.

What's the best way please ?

Comment: You can make it in [0;20] range and multiply value by 10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set value of .Net trackbar control with mouse, does not set value detween two points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634269/how-to-set-value-of-net-trackbar-control-with-mouse-does-not-set-value-detween)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `TrackBar` control hasn't any labels, you could use it for entering values and then multiply entered value by `10`. For instance:

```
mySlider.Minimum = 0;
mySlider.Maximum = 20;
mySlider.Value = 3;
mySlider.SmallChange = 1;
mySlider.LargeChange = 1;
mySlider.TickFrequency = 1;
```

But labels for the minimum and the maximum should display values multiplied by `10`.
And when entered value is requested, simply multiply it by `10`:

```
int someValue = mySlider.Value * 10;
```